# How can I get full payload from Moloch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, payload

I try to get full payload from Moloch by python2.7, but I just find scrPayload8 and dstPayload8(first eight byte of payload) in elasticsearch, moloch basic database.
where is the location of full payload in elasticsearch? 
Thanks a lot.

moloch version is 1.6.1
elasticsearch version is 6.4.2

Comment: What do you have so far? Any attempts?

Comment: Dear @UroshT., I already get dstIP, srcIP, port and request uri, except for full payload.

Comment: srcPayload8 and dstPayload8 are search queries.  To search the payloads, try the Hunt option (be sure to set your seession first).  Example: if you're looking for Bittorrent clients in your network, you'd use "d1:ad2:i" with the Payload8 queries, or you could "hunt" for the full "d1:ad2:id20:" string.  "d1:ad2:id20:" is the first 12 bytes of a DHT (Bittorrent) packet.